# Can't find my own comments on a huge string under a Facebook Live video

Tags: facebook, video, comments

I made a few comments on a White House live video on Facebook and then received notifications of two answers to one of my comments. When I click the notification it just takes me back to the video, which has maybe a million comments so I'll never find mine again to see the replies. Is there a way to search them efficiently? I did try to go into my activity log, and it shows my comments but will not let me click to take me to them to see the answers.